# Bouncy Castle: remove algorithm protection attribute from signerInfos

Tags: java, java-8, bouncycastle

I'm upgrading a system written in Java 6, using Bouncy Castle 1.43, which is used to generating CMS. New system is using Java 8 and Bouncy Castle 1.58 .

I have generated CMS using both and successfuly managed to verify them using openssl, unfortunately, third party, which receives the CMS rejects the one from the new system. My strong suspicion is that the reason behind it is the "Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) algorithm protection attribute" (OID: 1.2.840.113549.1.9.52), which is being added as part of the signerInfos->signedAttrs:

```
object: undefined (1.2.840.113549.1.9.52)
value.set:
              SEQUENCE:
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  30 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha512
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
   17:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  cont [ 1 ]        
   19:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha512WithRSAEncryption
   30:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL
```

This is the only significant difference I can see between the old and the new CMS. I tried setting the attribute table using setSignedAttributeGenerator(), however even though the algorithm protection is not set, this attribute is added. Is there a way to remove it without digging into the ASN1 and doing it manually?

This is how my CMS is created:

```
String signatureAlgorithm = "SHA512withRSA";
CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
ContentSigner shaSigner = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(signatureAlgorithm).build( privateKey );
gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new
                JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder( new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build())
                .build(shaSigner, certificate)
        );
gen.addCertificate( new X509CertificateHolder( certificate.getEncoded() ));

CMSTypedData processable = new CMSProcessableByteArray(toSign);
CMSSignedData signed = gen.generate(processable, true);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to do it by Overriding getAttributes() in DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator.

```
    SignerInfoGenerator sigGen = new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder( new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build())
            .build(shaSigner, certificate);

    final CMSAttributeTableGenerator sAttrGen = sigGen.getSignedAttributeTableGenerator();
    sigGen = new SignerInfoGenerator(sigGen, new
            DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(){
                @Override
                public AttributeTable getAttributes(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                                                            Map parameters) {
                    AttributeTable ret = sAttrGen.getAttributes(parameters);
                    return ret.remove(CMSAttributes.cmsAlgorithmProtect);
                }
            }, sigGen.getUnsignedAttributeTableGenerator());
    gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(sigGen);
```

Comment: In case one wanted to use a lambda:

`sigGen = new SignerInfoGenerator(sigGen, parameters -> sAttrGen.getAttributes(parameters).remove(CMSAttributes.cmsAlgorithmProtect), sigGen .getUnsignedAttributeTableGenerator());`